# How much effort does RDS save compared to hosting MySQL on EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I haven't managed a DB server before, so I wonder how much effort is saved if I use RDS rather than hosting MySQL on an EC2 instance. I know I probably won't need to spend a lot on setting it all up, but how much the rest? What kind of maintenance is there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You really should not set up a production MySQL instance on EC2 unless you REALLY know what you are doing.  First of all, EC2 instances are ephemeral in nature, meaning they are not really designed to hold persisted data.  If you wanted to use an EBS-backed instance or EBS volume , you can at least get around this issue, however your will have I/O performance issues with the EBS volume compared to local (ephemeral) disk storage. So if you plan on your database needing to meet any sort of high performance standard, this is pretty much a non-starter.

This is not to mention that with RDS you can a high-availability instance which will fail over to a synchronously replicated failover instance if needed.  You also get the ability for automated backups etc.

Certainly it will likely cost more for an RDS instance than running MySQL on EC2, but it is much less of a hassle, and significantly more performant.

Answer (score 0):

We run a multi-homed MySQL Database cluster in AWS, on EBS, and we're doing a million transactions a minute, so I don't foresee any I/O performance issues going that route. The question should be; do you have the time, desire, and ability within this project to learn MySQL, or do you want to farm it out for a slightly elevated cost. I'm sure you could get by with just setting up MySQL to start with (maybe a few hours of work) and then learn more about it in your down time, and tweaking it for performance gains as you near the upper limits of the current setup.

Answer (score 0):

For configuring MySQL on Amazon EC2 for a high volume DB , you need detailed understanding on Amazon EC2, VPC, EBS PIOPS, RAID, Backup strategies, Snapshot scripts, Replication architecture, monitoring plugins etc. RDS MySQL abstracts all these complexities and makes it simple for small teams to managed MySQL efficiently on AWS. It surely saves lots of labor hours for installation, configuration and maintenance for small teams.